# What is the faster method than array_diff() on PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I'm comparing two arrays which each have 5000 values. (An example value is: 123456789)

I want to know if there is a faster way to compare two arrays than `array_diff()`

Comment: Voting to close as dup but also upvoting since this question is much clearer and more accessible.

Comment: You need to ask yourself why you have an array with 5K elements in it.  If from a DB query you can run a limit via pagination, otherwise, there is no real reason to have an array this large.

Comment: @MikePurcell Since OP is dealing with numbers, it could be likely that the data is being fetched to create a CSV or Excel file for which 5k entries would be acceptable, just a guess though.

Comment: @crypticツ: then he should be approaching the using an unbuffered approach where we read the file line by line vs loading the entire file into memory.

Comment: @MikePurcell that would be if OP is reading a file, I was saying OP is *creating* a file by using data from database.

Comment: @crypticツ: Writing elements to a file via a query can be done in a paginated manner where this 'array' doesn't contain 5000 elements. Although it does result in more queries to the database.